# CSV file from Numbers on macOS Not Working on Google Colab

Tags: macos, data-science, google-colaboratory

```
from google.colab import files
file = files.upload()

df = pd.read_csv('Book 1.xlsx')
df.head(10)

print(df['id'])
```

When I run this I get a key error for id, which is the first header name in my dataset.
I created this file in numbers by copy pasting text in csv format to a blank numbers spreadsheet and exporting as a csv file. I have "use header names as labels" on in preferences. I have recently gotten my MacBook so there may be some small detail I am overlooking. I have also tried removing footer rows but it isn't working. Please help.

Comment: Sometimes there would be spaces within the columns' names. Try to run ```df.columns``` to make sure it is only ```'id'``` and not ```'   id'```.

Comment: I tried this and the column label was 'id'

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the head as example because now we are just guessing. And also you are loading a .xlsx file with `pd.read_csv` while you have the `pd.read_excel` function in pandas. Maybe that helps?

Also Mohana's answer is worth trying. You are looking on a string and it can be different than you think.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that I was using read_csv for the xlsx file. I don't know what happened exactly but everything is working right now as long as I use google sheets. I tried using google sheets earlier and the same error was occurring but now its working somehow. I loaded a Kaggle dataset to google sheets to try to understand what mistake I was and then I read that dataset with Colab and then I remade the old dataset I was using by importing a txt file (exactly like I did last time) to google sheets, uploaded it to Colab and then it started working.

Comment: So case closed? :)

Comment: Yeah I guess. Its quite an unsatisfactory result but at least its working